# WebSocketService - закрытие соединения с причиной

Tags: c#, websocket, wcf

Использую класс наследник `Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets`. В нем нет способа передать в метод `Close();` причину закрытия, в ходе изысканий наткнулся на такой способ:

```
public override void OnOpen()
{
        //Достаем некий токен из WebSocketContext.Headers["token"]
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        {     
            WebSocketContext.WebSocket
                            .CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.PolicyViolation, $"Socket token={token} is unknown - rejected!", new CancellationToken())
                            .Wait();
            return;
        }
}
```

"Оппа!" - подумал я - то что нужно... "Фиг тебе" - сказал `WCF`, и вынес с ноги эксепшеном "К объекту WebSocket нельзя обращаться напрямую". 
Есть ли еще какие-то варианты?